# graph inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, linker-errors

I have implemented the following class

```
class graph {
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, graph&);
public:
    graph() { }
    ~graph() { clearMap(); }

    class node {
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const graph::node&);
    public:
        node() { }
        node(const node&);
        node(luint inID) { ID = inID; }
        virtual ~node() { neighbors.clear(); }

        node& operator=(const node&);
        void addNeighbor(luint);
        void addNeighbor(const std::vector<luint>& );

        luint ID;
        std::vector<luint> neighbors;
    };

    void addNode(const node&);
    void addNode(const node*);
    void addNode(luint);
    void readFile(const char * );
    void clearMap();

    void randGeom(luint, double);
    void connRandGeom(luint, double);
    bool isConnected();


protected:
    std::map<luint, node*> nodeMap;
};
```

and created a new one, inherited from graph

```
class colorGraph : public graph {
public:
    colorGraph() { }
    ~colorGraph() { }

    class colorNode : public graph::node {
    public:
        colorNode() { }
        ~colorNode() { }

        luint color;
    };
};
```

However, the following main program does not find the proper function:

```
int main() {
    pColorGraph myGraph;
    myGraph = new colorGraph();
    myGraph->isConnected();
    return 0;
}
```

> Undefined symbols:
>   "graph::isConnected()", referenced
>   from:
>         _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: You never actually wrote the implementation for `graph::isConnected()`?!

Answer (score 0):

The function has no implementation!  It's just the header of it.

Comment: shouldn't it be derived from graph?

Comment: I see, I did not include graph.cpp. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Included graph.cpp. Solved

Comment: graph.cpp shouldn't be included via `#include`, if that's what you're referring to. It should be compiled separately, then linked with `main.o` when creating the executable (e.g. when compiling with GCC: `g++ graph.o main.o -o main`).  See ["What is the conventions for headers and cpp files in C++?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540140/what-is-the-conventions-for-headers-and-cpp-files-in-c) and search for info on the link phase for more on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is "pColorGraph" in your code?
2. Do you have an implementation for "isConnected()" in "class graph"?