# c++: issue with main()? - a function-declaration is not allowed here before '{' token

Tags: c++

I'm getting two compile errors:

```
/home/sater/projects/MotionManager/videoProcess.cpp:11:1: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
/home/sater/projects/MotionManager/main.cpp:85:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
```

I checked to make sure that all parentheses and brackets were matched, but can't find the root of this problem.  Could you please take a look at my code to see if I'm misunderstanding something?  I'm new to c++ and am coming from mostly web programming and scripting experience but I'm a learn by doing sort of person so please excuse any mistakes due to not having "read my book" because I don't have one.  A simple explanation or link to more information about my failure would be helpful.

It seems like there must be some problem in the way I call the processVideoFile function, but I can't figure out what I did wrong.  Thanks for spending the time to take a look.

main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include "parseMotion.cpp"
#include "resumepause.cpp"
#include "videoProcess.cpp"

using namespace std;

bool DEBUG = true;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //Useful directory strings
    string camDir [3];
    camDir[0]= "cam01(Outside)/";
    camDir[1]= "cam02(Upper)/";
    camDir[2]= "cam03(Lower)/";

    string latestWD = "/Store/SecurityStorage/LatestVideos/";
    string archiveWD = "/Store/SecurityStorage/VideoArchive/";

    int threadStatus [3];
    threadStatus[0] = 0;
    threadStatus[1] = 0;
    threadStatus[2] = 0;
    //-50 paused
    //-1 couldn't connect initially to camera
    //0 Not yet started
    //1 Started successfully
    //2 lost connection to cam - retrying

    deque<string> fileDeque;
    deque<int> fileTimingDeque;



    int exitTrig = -1;
    int counter = 0;

    FILE *MotionIOStream = popen("motion 2>&1", "r");
    if(!MotionIOStream){
      exitTrig = 1;
    }
    while( exitTrig < 0 )
    {      
      //Set maximum length, fgets: get one line
      char buffer[1024]; 
      string lineOutput;
      lineOutput = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), MotionIOStream);

      //check mysqldb for pause/resume
      int rpResult;
      rpResult = checkSchedule(threadStatus);
      if(rpResult != 0)
      {
    return rpResult;
      }

      //process video - fork
      int pid;
      pid = processVideoFiles(fileDeque, fileTimingDeque);
      if(pid == 0)
      {
    return 0;
      }

      //cout << "Starting to parse" << endl;
      parseMotionOutput(lineOutput, threadStatus, fileDeque, fileTimingDeque);

      counter++;
      //[3] Thread 3 started
      if( counter > 20 )
      {
    exitTrig = 2;
    pclose(MotionIOStream);
    system("killall motion");
    return 0;
      }
    }
    //Handle error returns here.
    //case 1: "Couldn't start motion."
    //case 2: ""
    return 0;
}
```

Here is videoProcess.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive_static.hpp>

using namespace boost::xpressive;

int processVideoFiles( std::deque<std::string> &fileDeque, std::deque<int> &fileTimingDeque )
{

  std::time_t secondsNow;
  secondsNow = std::time(NULL);

  int nextFileSeconds = fileTimingDeque.front();
  int diff = secondsNow - nextFileSeconds;
  if( diff > 120)
  {
    //Should fork
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
      //Is child
      std::string filePath = fileDeque.front();
      mark_tag wd(1), camDir(2), dateDir(3), fileName(4);
      // /Store/SecurityStorage/LatestVideos/cam03(Lower)/2011-07-21/01-20110721112236.avi
      sregex pathRegex =  (wd= "/Store/SecurityStorage/LatestVideos/") >> (camDir= ("cam0" >> range('1', '3') >> '/') ) >> (dateDir= ( repeat<4,4>(range('0', '9')) >> '-' >> '0' | '1' >> range( '0', '9' ) >> '/') ) >> (fileName= ( repeat<2,2>(range('0','9')) >> '-' >> repeat<14,14>(range('0','9')) >> '.' >> "avi" ) ) ;
      smatch pathWhat;
      if( regex_search(filePath, pathWhat, pathRegex) )
      {
    std::cout << "The working directory for this file is:" << pathWhat[wd] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The camera directory for this file is:" << pathWhat[camDir] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The date directory for this file is:" << pathWhat[dateDir] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The filename of this file is:" << pathWhat[fileName] << std::endl;
      }else
      {
    std::cout << "Error: Couldn't match the file path regex." << std::endl;
    return 0;
      }

      //mplayer $filepath -vo jpeg -ao null -frames 25
      std::string commandString = "mplayer " + filePath + " -vo jpeg -ao null -frames 25";
      const char* commandChar = commandString.c_str();

      int commandResult = system(commandChar);
      if(commandResult != 0)
      {
    std::cout << "Couldn't create jpeg files for some reason" << endl;
      }else
      {
    return 0;
      }

      //Last steps
      fileDeque.pop_front();
      fileTimingDeque.pop_front();
    }
      return pid;
  }else
  {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: OT, but why are you including .cpp files? And please indent your code properly.

Comment: You are missing a closing paren somewhere.

Comment: You should try to reduce this -- a *lot* -- before you post it here and ask us what's wrong with it.

Comment: Something amiss in `videoProcess.cpp` which you include, which is bad btw.

Comment: What's wrong with including .cpp files?  How else do I include functions defined in a different file.
Also, how can I reduce my code if I don't know what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Kelly, here's one answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540140/what-is-the-conventions-for-headers-and-cpp-files-in-c/540159#540159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have forgot to put `;` after a class declaration somewhere, or forgot to put a matching `}`. The error is most likely in one of your header files that you haven't shown.

Comment: Concur. That is a typical error signature for a missing semicolon on a class definition, at least for g++. Compilers try to "fix" syntax errors so they can proceed. (Compilers that stop at the first error are an incredible pain to deal with.) Unfortunately, g++ makes an incredibly bad correction to the (very common) missing semicolon problem.

Comment: @David: Good news is that latest version of gcc now points out exact place where `;` is missing. I think they have fixed it starting 4.5 or 4.6..

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise this mistake could be made by the compiler.  One of my other files was missing a curly bracket due to a large number of conditional statements and careless typing.

Comment: @Kelly: I'm glad you found it. Compile the code more often while making changes - it makes it easier to track down errors like this.

Comment: @Vlad - thanks for the tip.  This was a massive addition to my code and I went against my better judgement in not compiling because my system is quite slow.  I will compile much more often from now on.

Answer (score 1):

The `main` definition seems correct, so there has to be an error in one of the included files. Including a `.cpp` file is not recommended practice, btw., and not doing that makes these kinds of errors much easier to debug.

Comment: How do I successfully modularise the program without including cpp files?  They all contain a single function for convenience sake.
I'm sorry I don't really know standard practice.

Comment: @Kelly Sater: you declare the functions in a common header file, then `#include` that in each module. Pick up any good book on C++ to see how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

As larsmans suggests, this is caused by some stale definition on the previous headers. Try removing them and leaving just one of them to see which one introduces the error. Also, another trick could be to use `cpp` directly to produce just one big file, and then edit it into an editor with syntax highlighting to see where you're missing a bracket, etc.:

cpp -Iinclude_dirs main.cpp > output_file.cpp

Comment: Thanks, your advice was helpful in determining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the header `<deque>` included?

Also, can you put the other two files you are including, in particular the `resumepause.cpp` file

Comment: Is it included in stdlib?  My IDE didn't give an error, so I assumed it was included in one of the header files I'd already included.

Comment: its in the stl.  the boost header probably includes deque, but I didnt check it